# how to define the temporary folder that ClickOnce extract the files to?

Tags: c#, winforms, publish

I've created a winforms appliction and i need to check if .NET4 installed on the machine before starting the application.

im using the "Publish" option, it works great BUT im looking for a way to define the temporary folder where all the application files will be extracted to

the current behaiver is that when im starting the files that the Publish created ,it extracting all my application to :

C:\Users\shacharsa\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\057V8G8X.MXV\6482W7L5.25P\smar..tion_30394eeddffd8a96_0001.0000_5bb050675a14dcbe\Files

and i want it to extract them to c:\temp

thanks,

shachar.

Comment: clickonce is designed to install for the current user with minimal user rights. why do you want to extract it to `c:\temp`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't define the location, however a better solution to your problem is available. You should read up on the ClickOnce bootstrapper and using that to detect and install prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, it is part of how ClickOnce works, its security model will not allow for that to happen.